# Moment js formating hours and showing time in minutes and seconds format

Tags: jquery, momentjs

friends. I have problem with my script. I need to convert 1:20:22 into 80:22.
And it don't show seconds correct.
I try this:

```
var eventTime = moment('1:12:22', 'hh:mm:ss');
var terribleTime = (eventTime.hour()*60) + eventTime.minute() + ':' + eventTime.seconds();
```

if I use "00" seconds it shows me only 1 zero, like that: "12:0":
[image: second problem]

**Answer on my question, If somebody need the answer in future!!!**

```
var terribleTime = moment(eventTime).hours()*60 + moment(eventTime).minutes() + ':' + moment(eventTime).format('ss');
```

Comment: Sory friend, I'm find answer on self questions)) var terribleTime = moment(eventTime).hours()*60 + moment(eventTime).minutes() + ':' + moment(eventTime).format('ss');

Comment: Post your answer and accept it for those who may find this from google

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle with your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9eafza1q/

JS - using Jquery 1.9.1 & momentjs 2.8.3 :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var eventTime = moment('1:12:22', 'hh:mm:ss');
    var terribleTime = moment(eventTime).hour()*60 + moment(eventTime).minute() + ':' + moment(eventTime).seconds();
    console.log(terribleTime);
   });
```

EDIT: In this fiddle you have annother approach. There is no need to create a moment for every hour,minute,seconds function as the eventTime is a moment object.

http://jsfiddle.net/o85tmsv6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var eventTime = moment('1:12:22', 'hh:mm:ss');
    var terribleTime = eventTime.hour()*60 + eventTime.minute() + ':' + eventTime.seconds();
    console.log(terribleTime);
   });
```

This is tested too in chrome, ie, ff & safari.

Comment: It dont solve the problem with seconds. But thanks for validate it.

Comment: it works for seconds too without "ss" format, at least in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/9eafza1q/1/ here is 80:22 what u want to accomplish

Comment: i test this in the chrome, safari, ie & firefox. everything was allright. What browser are you using ? Otherwise you can accept the answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I did it without moment. It seemed too much involved using internal functions of moment and it is a heavy library wrt size.

```js
const getMinutesSeconds = (seconds = 0) => {
    const newMinutes = seconds >= 60 ? parseInt(seconds / 60, 10) : 0
    const newSeconds = parseInt(seconds % 60, 10)
    return newMinutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" + newSeconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')
}

console.log(getMinutesSeconds(1236))
console.log(getMinutesSeconds(65))
console.log(getMinutesSeconds(121))
console.log(getMinutesSeconds(180))
```

Here you will get output in `mm:ss` format, appending 0 before if it is single digit.